# jquery validation on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a form that i am trying to validate. I have a field that i want to make sure is required. I have the following code for the field:

```
<p>
   <label for="lf">Name: </label>
   <input class="lf" name="name" type="text"/> 
   <span id="name_error" class="validate_error">Please enter a valid name!</span>
</p>
```

I want to be able to first off if they click in the box and don't type anything and then go to a different box, i want the span tag to show and also if they hit submit and didn't type anything.

I have the following jquery code, but it always shows the span tag no matter what.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    <!--Name can't be blank-->
    $('#name').on('input', function() {
        var input=$(this);
        var is_name=input.val();
            if(is_name){
                $("#name_error").hide();
            }else{
                $("#name_error").show();
            }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: btw, ``<!-- -->`` is only for commenting html, not js.

Comment: Simple as: `$('#name').on('input blur', function() {`

Comment: Just use [jQuery Validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/); this problem is _beyond_ solved.

Comment: **validator** is the greatest plugin for this! - http://dropthebit.com/demos/validator/validator.html

Answer (score 2):

You are targeting with id, but the element does not have an id.

Either set `id="name"` on the input element

```
<input class="lf" id="name" name="name" type="text"/>
```

or use another selector `input[name="name"]` when targeting it.

```
$('input[name="name"]').on('input', function() {
```

(*additionally, that html comment should not be there or it should have a `//` at the beginning*)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
$('input.lf').on('blur', function() {
    var input=$(this);
    var is_name=input.val();
        if(is_name){
            $("#name_error").hide();
        }else{
            $("#name_error").show();
        }
});
```

you have no name id on the input, sorry just noticed and fixed

Comment: same thing it always just shows there and no matter what it doesn't hide

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('#name').on('blur', function() {
    var input=$(this);

    var is_name = input.val();

     if(is_name){
         $("#name_error").hide();
     }else{
         $("#name_error").show();
     }
 });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UR8m4/1/

You had a few problems, first, you didn't have the id #name on your input.
Second, you need to hide the error with css to begin with.
Third, you need to bind to the blur event.